# Need to get ip informat

Tags: java

I am using the PrintService class to get the details of the currently attached printer now I have a requirement to get the IP of the attached printer.

I am able to get the names of all the attached printer but not able to get the IP.

```
PrintService[] printServices = 
     PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);  
System.out.println("Number of print services: " + printServices.length);  

for (PrintService printer : printServices)  
  //System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName());   
  System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName());   
}
```

Can someone let me know how can i get the IP of the printer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [InetAddress.getByName](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) a try. I can't know for sure that the printer name in this case actually is a true network/DNS name but if it does, then that'll get what you need.

```
String ip = InetAddress.getByName(printer.getName()).toString()
```

Comment: This is not working coz printer is not configured with the host name...any other way of doing it? Using printservice classes??